# How to select a specific start for an increment and reset it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ive been spending countless hours trying to figure it out.What I am trying to make is an animating slide show.I have 6 buttons underneath and lets say for ex i click on btn 4 the increment starts at 4 i++.And if i click on btn 1 it would restart/reset the loop and increment starts at 1 and i++.I hope its understandable.Dont worry about the img as much the main focus is the reset of the increment and the starting when clicked on.

```
                js
                    var imgArray = 
      ["img1","img2","img3","img4","img5","img6"],
       imgDuration = 2000;index=0;i=0;


       $("input").on("click",function(){
        resume()
          })

         function resume(){
           var value = $("input:checked").val();
           value++;
           console.log(value)
           if (value == imgArray.length) {
           value =0
           }time = setTimeout(resume,imgDuration);
           }
```

html

```
        <div class="radio-case">
        <form class="radio-btn">
            <input name="imgbtn" checked="true" value="0" type="radio">
            <input name="imgbtn" value="1" type="radio">
            <input name="imgbtn" value="2" type="radio">
            <input name="imgbtn" value="3" type="radio">
            <input name="imgbtn" value="4" type="radio">
            <input name="imgbtn" value="5" type="radio">
        </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: You might want to take some time to clean up the indenting so it's readable.

Comment: And to get even more help, turn this into a working snippet.. click the `<>` icon in the editor to get a kind of JSfiddle editor..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basic problem is that every time you call `resume()` you set `value` to the selected button's value. You then increment this, but when you call `resume()` again it sets it back to what it was.

There are a lot of ways to fix this. The quickest (but maybe not the best) is to make `value` a variable outside the scope of `resume()` and set it with the click handler not `resume()`. Then when you increment it inside `resume()`, it will stick.

I would also suggest using `setInterval()` rather than calling `setTimeout` each time. It's easier to control and prevent more timers than intended from running.

For example:

```js
var imgArray = ["img1", "img2", "img3", "img4", "img5", "img6"]
var imgDuration = 2000
var value = 0
var interval

$("input").on("click", function() {
  clearInterval(interval)
  value = $("input:checked").val();
  interval = setInterval(resume, imgDuration)
})

function resume() {
  console.log(imgArray[value % imgArray.length]);
  value++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-case">
  <form class="radio-btn">
    <input name="imgbtn" checked="true" value="0" type="radio">
    <input name="imgbtn" value="1" type="radio">
    <input name="imgbtn" value="2" type="radio">
    <input name="imgbtn" value="3" type="radio">
    <input name="imgbtn" value="4" type="radio">
    <input name="imgbtn" value="5" type="radio">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: that was what i was looking for setInterval().Thanks alot man really appreciate ur help :)